# Bind events to custom component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Using Vue3

I'm creating a custom component and would like to bind the events to the input inside it. So in this case I would like to do something similar as I do with the `v-bind="inputProps"`. How is it done now `$listeners` are being removed? As you probably can see I'm not in a position to use `v-bind="$attrs"` as the properties are divided to where they "go".

I'm here to solve a problem but any hints on improvement is always a welcome bonus.

// c-text.vue

```
<template>
  <input
    v-if="useAsSingleElement"
    v-bind="inputProps"
    :class="['c-text', 'c-text--is-single-element']"
    @input="$emit('input', $event)"
    @blur="$emit('blur')"
    @focus="$emit('focus')">

  <c-form-item-shell
    v-else
    :id="id"
    :is-required="isRequired"
    :label-text="labelText"
    :icon="icon"
    :icon-class="iconClass"
    :errors="errors"
    :information="information">
    <template #element>
      <input
        v-bind="inputProps"
        class="c-text"
        @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
        @blur="$emit('blur')"
        @focus="$emit('focus')">
    </template>
  </c-form-item-shell>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import CFormItemShell from '@/components/c-form-item-shell.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    CFormItemShell
  },
  props: {
    useAsSingleElement: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    type: { type: String, required: false, default: 'text' },
    placeholder: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    maxlength: { type: [String, Number], required: false, default: null },
    minxlength: { type: [String, Number], required: false, default: null },
    pattern: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    readonly: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    spellcheck: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    autocomplete: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: true },
    id: { type: String, required: true },
    isRequired: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    labelText: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    icon: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    iconClass: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    errors: { type: [String, Array], required: false, default: null },
    information: { type: [String, Array], required: false, default: null }
  },
  emits: ['input', 'blur', 'focus'],
  setup (props) {
    const inputProps = computed(() => {
      return {
        id: props.id,
        name: props.name ? props.name : props.id,
        type: props.type,
        placeholder: props.placeholder,
        maxlength: props.maxlength,
        minlength: props.minlength,
        pattern: props.pattern,
        readonly: props.readonly,
        spellcheck: props.spellcheck,
        autocomplete: props.autocomplete ? 'on' : 'off'
      }
    })

    return {
      inputProps
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html#_3-x-syntax) :

> In Vue 3's virtual DOM, event listeners are now just attributes, prefixed with `on`, and as such are part of the `$attrs` object, so `$listeners` has been removed.

so just pass your events like `onClick`, `onBlur` ... and

```
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false
}
```

Comment: I saw the docs but not sure how to use it. Three main things that are unclear. 1. is it enough to do `<c-text @click="something" />` and not emit in the component? 2. how could I collect all events into one computed? 3. how do I bind that computed to the input?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question and more of a detailed answer in the hopes that it can help anybody in the future. Thanks to Boussadjra Brahim who's answer got me thinking. I did the following

1. added `inhertsAttrs: false`
   [Link to docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs)

This makes it so the events (meaning your `@input`, `@click` ect) on the component don't get applied to the parent node

2. added `emits: ['update:modelValue', 'blur', 'focus']` 
   [Link to docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/emits-option.html#emits-option)

This should be all of the emits that you want to capture and emit back

3. "Collect" the emits manually to my `propsAndListeners` object like this. Then bind it to the input like `<input v-bind="propsAndListeners" />`

Keep in mind that you have to prefix your events with `on` so if you have a `@click` event that will have the name `onClick` in the `$attrs` (@ short is v-on)

```
const propsAndListeners = computed(() => {
  return {
    onInput: (event) => emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
  }
})
```

In most cases you probably would bind the `$attrs` to a element but the reason for the `propsAndListeners` is that I have `if` condition and binding the same things for an input in two places.

Here is the full script part

```
export default {
  components: {
    CFormItemShell
  },
  props: {
    useAsSingleElement: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    type: { type: String, required: false, default: 'text' },
    modelValue: { type: [String, Number, Date], required: false, default: null },
    placeholder: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    maxlength: { type: [String, Number], required: false, default: null },
    minxlength: { type: [String, Number], required: false, default: null },
    pattern: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    readonly: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    spellcheck: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    autocomplete: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: true },
    id: { type: String, required: true },
    isRequired: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    labelText: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    icon: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    iconClass: { type: String, required: false, default: null },
    errors: { type: [String, Array], required: false, default: null },
    information: { type: [String, Array], required: false, default: null }
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue', 'blur', 'focus'],
  setup (props, { emit }) {
    const propsAndListeners = computed(() => {
      return {
        id: props.id,
        name: props.name ? props.name : props.id,
        type: props.type,
        placeholder: props.placeholder,
        value: props.modelValue,
        maxlength: props.maxlength,
        minlength: props.minlength,
        pattern: props.pattern,
        readonly: props.readonly,
        spellcheck: props.spellcheck,
        autocomplete: props.autocomplete ? 'on' : 'off',
        onInput: (event) => emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value),
        onBlur: (event) => emit('blur', event),
        onFocus: (event) => emit('focus', event)
      }
    })

    return {
      propsAndListeners
    }
  }
}
```